# Should I use connection-pooling in multi-threaded program?

Tags: java, database, multithreading, database-connection, connection-pooling

I am using multiple threads to insert insert records in different tables. In addition, I am using batch processing for the insertion of records to improve the efficiency.

Note: Number of records to be inserted are in millions.

My question is **should I use connection pooling in this multi-threaded environment?**

**My Concern:**

Each threads gonna run for quite sometime to perform the database operation. So, if the size of my connection pool is 2 and number of threads are 4,then at a given moment only 2 threads are gonna run. Consequently, other 2 threads gonna sit ideal for a long time to get the connection, as the db operations for million records are time consuming. Moreover, such connection-pooling will hinder the purpose of using multiple threads.

Comment: so collection pool should be of size that is equal to number of threads.

Comment: then what will we the use of connection-pool? As we can create n number of connections anyways without using the connection-pool.

Comment: Establishing connection is time consuming. Better to do it once.

Answer (score 1):

Using a connection pool in a batch is a matter of convenciency. It will help you limit the amount of open connections, abandoned time, close connections if you forget to close them verify if the connection is open etc.

Check out the Plain Ol' Java example [here](https://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html)

Comment: Exactly. While you might not need it or get the same advantages as with regular OLTP, there's certainly no harm in it.

Comment: If I am handling the connection judiciously, then their is no need of using connection-pool(Acc. to my use case)? Am I right? Btw I tried the commons-dbcp.

Comment: I guess you could do the same with an appropriate connection pool and configuration. For instance maxActive in your case would be 2 and the maxWait property would make thread num. 3 wait until a connection is available for an specified period but yet again a pool is for convenience if it's complicating things for you don't use it.